# Change part of excel formula with a constant value

Tags: excel, formula, increment, radix

I have an excel formula across a column for which the base changes every "x" number of rows. Note this "x" is not constant and keeps changing. e.g.

```
=D1/SUM(D$1:D$4)
=D2/SUM(D$1:D$4)
=D3/SUM(D$1:D$4)
=D4/SUM(D$1:D$4)
=D5/SUM(D$5:D$9)
=D6/SUM(D$5:D$9)
=D7/SUM(D$5:D$9)
=D8/SUM(D$5:D$9)
=D9/SUM(D$5:D$9)
```

I am trying to change the first part of the formulas without changing the second and vice versa. e.g. changing the numerator by 10 cells.

```
=D11/SUM(D$1:D$4)
=D12/SUM(D$1:D$4)
=D13/SUM(D$1:D$4)
=D14/SUM(D$1:D$4)
=D15/SUM(D$5:D$9)
=D16/SUM(D$5:D$9)
=D17/SUM(D$5:D$9)
=D18/SUM(D$5:D$9)
=D19/SUM(D$5:D$9)
```

or, changing the base by 100. e.g.

```
=D1/SUM(D$100:D$104)
=D2/SUM(D$100:D$104)
=D3/SUM(D$100:D$104)
=D4/SUM(D$100:D$104)
=D5/SUM(D$105:D$109)
=D6/SUM(D$105:D$109)
=D7/SUM(D$105:D$109)
=D8/SUM(D$105:D$109)
=D9/SUM(D$105:D$109)
```

Sometimes, both. Any guidance on how this can be possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to do it one time? or is it supposed to change like once a week?

Comment: One time, but it is such a long list of formulas that i dont want to change every cell by a constant value manually

Comment: how many distinct ranges (denominators) are there?

Comment: @Jon, 3 segments, each having 10. So 30 in total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the first part of this problem seems easy unless I am missing something?

Part 1:

Since the denominator is already in $x form, you can select and COPY the whole range of formulas and PASTE them 10 rows down and then CUT and paste it back into position.  The COPY will update the numerators appropriately and when you CUT and PASTE it back into position they will now be just as you want?  The second question will be a bit more of a challenge!

Part 2:

OK without VBA I can only think of a really long-winded way to change your demoninators, but I just checked that it does work:
To change the bottom.

1. Search and replace = with '=

Now you can edit the formulas more freely.

2. Search and replace D with D%
3. Search and replace D%$ with D
4. Search and replace D% with D$
5. get rid of the '= by using the Data>text to columns option
6. Now use the copy and paste, cut paste trick from part 1.

Then if you still need your $s back as they were you essentially repeat 1 to 5 again.
Sorry, this looks really long-winded, but if you are desperate and back up before you start it should work.

Answer (score 1):

An excel formula can't replace another cells excel formula... One approach is to make the formula into text and then transform it by other formulas. When transformation is done, you could paste the formula back.

So for changing the `D1` -> `D11`, I would build a dummy series (column `K`) then write a formula (cell `L1`). Then I can copy the formula and paste it into the correct column.

Replaceing the "=", with a special character and then you can transform the formulas.
(Column F).

In Column I, the formula used is: `=RIGHT(F1,LEN(F1)-FIND("/",F1))`

[image]

For changing `D$1` -> `D$100`, I think I just would copy and replace it by searching in "Formulas".

[image]

This approach can be feasible for acouple of hundred cells. If the list is very long, I would recommend some VBA solution, where you can grab a cells formula with `.Range("A1").Formula`